# How can I get the value of a Zend_Form in zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend_Form called login.php in my zend project.

In controller I have

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
        $request->setMethod('post')
                ->setPost(array(
                    'username' => 'admin',
                    'password' => '111111',
                ));
        $this->dispatch('/en/auth/login');
        $values = $form->getValues();
```

I wonder how can I get values from this form? $form->getValues() will return a array? and how to get the username and password form it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{
   if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())
   {
      //Here is form->getValue() enabled
      echo $form->getValue('elementName');
   }
}
```

getValue isn't available unti the form is valid

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
$values = $form->getValues();

$username = $values['username'];
$password = $values['password'];
```

and if are using:

```
$form->setElementBelongsTo(´login');
```

then you need to call the ElementBelongsTo string first.

```
$values = $form->getValues();

$username = $values['login']['username'];
$password = $values['login']['password'];
```